# When i can call getGeofenceLocations from server for geofencing in android

Tags: android, geolocation, geofencing

I want to do geofencing feature for android app. As we can add only 100 locations for geofening in android. I want to call the webservice based on the locations.

Ex: If i am in x location area i will call the webservice and get the nearby locations, if i move to y location (atleast 500 m distance) then call the webservice to get nearby locations.

Is this approach can be done in android? or i need to follow any other approach. I know in iOS this can be achieved by significant location change method.

Comment: Can't say that I'm exactly sure what the question is here? What webservice?

Comment: @SimonH Its my own webservice written in server side to fetch the nearby locations data from the server

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by calling the web service every time a user's location changes. Then use the data from the web service to create a geofence for each location returned by the web service and handle the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use getLastKnownLocation and save it in sharedprefrance then use distanceTo method to compare and calculate then do your web service call 
getLastKnownLocation will give you last location without battery consumption 
for getLastKnownLocation check out this

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

for distanceTo you have to give it two locations then you will receive distance between them.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)

Comment: You should describe the content in the links you post, as good practice. Avoid just posting a link as the main point of the answer post.